# freeradius + ldap 389 DS

Tags: ldap, freeradius

I'm using freeradius server to return the group name, the LDAP is 389 DS:

```
In /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap:

ldap {
         server = 'freeipa.dc=server,dc=example,dc=com
#       port = 389
#       identity = 'cn=admin,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com'
#       password = mypass
         base_dn = 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com'
         ...
}

group {
          base_dn = 'cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com'
          dc=example,dc=com
          name_attribute = cn
          membership_filter = "(|(member=%{control:Ldap-UserDn})(memberUid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}}))"
          membership_attribute = memberOf
          ...
}
```

The debug:

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (2)
(0)     Using user DN from request "uid=ttest2,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com"
(0)     Checking for user in group objects
(0)       EXPAND (&(cn=ipausers)(objectClass=ipausergroup)(|(member=%{control:Ldap-UserDn})(memberUid=%{%{Stripped-User-Name}:-%{User-Name}})))
(0)          --> (&(cn=ipausers)(objectClass=ipausergroup)(|(member=uid\3dttest2\2ccn\3dusers\2ccn\3daccounts\2cdc\3dserver\2cdc\3dexample\2cdc\3dcom)(memberUid=ttest2)))
(0)       Performing search in "cn=ipausers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com" with filter "(&(cn=ipausers)(objectClass=ipausergroup)(|(member=uid\3dttest2\2ccn\3dusers\2ccn\3daccounts\2cdc\3dserver\2cdc\3dexample\2cdc\3dcom)(memberUid=ttest2)))", scope "sub"
(0)       Waiting for search result...
(0)       Search returned no results
(0)     Checking user object's memberOf attributes
(0)       Performing unfiltered search in "uid=ttest2,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=server,dc=example,dc=com", scope "base"
(0)       Waiting for search result...
(0)     No group membership attribute(s) found in user object
```

But the filter isn't returning any results (0) Search returned no results !! I'm missing something ?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you run the equivalent query with the ldapsearch utility?

Comment: The memberOf attribute is an attribute in users (and the values are DNs of the groups). The search base and membership filter is only searching under cn=groups for group entries that have the member attribute with the appropriate value. That search returns groups not users.